# How Do I Stop Links From Redirecting Me to Different Sites in the Ubuntu Chromium browser?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, chromium

When I am opening a new link web page in the new tab, the actual(previous) tab is automatically redirecting to the some other websites. Seems to be browser is affected by the malware. However, after deleting cookies and uninstalling and reinstalling the browser does not yield a good result. Please ping me how to fix this Ubuntu 14.04 chromium issue.